# Force an application to use 90% of the cpu, mac

Tags: mac, cpu-usage, utilization

a software that I downloaded is kinda running slow and I guess it could run a bit faster, so I wondered: Can you force an application to use 90% of the cpu (90% not 100% {leave 10% for other stuff})?

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: So it's software you downloaded? Then you're on the wrong site. This is for programming related questions.

Comment: sorry then , i just wanted help

Comment: @nubegeek: that ok, but try http://superuser.com instead. Your question is more appropriate there.

Comment: If an application is slow, and uses less than the maximum available CPU, the CPU is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple... This is very possible and I use it all the time for crunching videos and other stuff. Basically you want to use process-renicer ([noxeos](http://www.noxeos.com/2011/01/29/process-renicer/)). This application can control the processing for any process.

But be careful, you may seriously impact the operating system if you don't watch out!

Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

Applications will normally use whatever processing power is available.  If your application is consuming very little processing time, then it's probably because it's waiting for other processes (e.g., waiting for information from a web site, a slow disk, etc.).

Some modern Operating Systems may allow you to set a maximum limit on processor utilization on a per-application/process basis.  If you're using the newer generation Unix-based MacOS, there's a command called "nice" which will be of interest to you -- if you can get to a shell (command-line prompt) Console, you can type this command to view the documentation:  man nice